# MySQL Joins - Loop through all categories and output items

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

My tables:

Categories:

```
id (int)
name (varchar)
```

Items:

```
id (int)
name (varchar)
category (int)
```

Is it possible to use output the data like this:

```
Category1
---------
Item1
Item2

Category2
---------
Item3
Item4
```

Using JOIN? I am able to do it like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM categories");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo $row["name"];

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dishes WHERE category = {$row["id"]}");

    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2))
    {
        echo ...
    }
}
```

However, as you may know, this is a terrible way to do this and it should never be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, use a JOIN, then order by category. Inside your PHP you just check if the category has changed to the next, and if so, show a nice table heading (code pending)

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT dishes.id, dishes.name, categories.name as catname, categories.id as catid FROM dishes LEFT JOIN categories ON (dishes.category=categories.id) ORDER BY categories.name ASC");

$currCat = 0;
while($dish = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
   if($currCat != $dish['catid']) {
      echo 'Category: ' . $dish['catname'];
      $currCat = $dish['catid'];
   }
   echo $dish['name'];
}

mysql_free_result($q);
```

On a sidenote, you really should NOT be using the mysql extension anymore. It has been *deprecated*. Instead you should use either the MySQLi or PDO extensions.

Comment: Thanks! and I know ... I just put together this code to demonstrate what I was doing :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$SQL = "SELECT c.name, d.*
        FROM categories AS c
        JOIN dishes AS d ON ( d.category = c.id ) 
        ORDER BY c.name ASC";

$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die (mysql_error());

$oldCategory = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if( $oldCategory != $row["name"] )
    {
         echo $row["name"]; 

         $oldCategory = $row["name"];
    }

    print_r( $row );
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

**NB** mysql_* is deprecated... use mysqli_* or pdo!